# YoloV5 way too less FPS, how can I fix it?

Tags: performance, artificial-intelligence, real-time, object-detection, yolov5

**Can you help me to improve my FPS with Yolov5s?**

I am using yolov5s for Real-Time detection in a game, but I do have very less FPS (about 30-40) and sometimes only 0.
I am using it with my custom dataset:

```
model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'custom', path=r'C:\Users\stefa\Downloads\best2.pt') # local repo
```

And with mss to screen capture:

```
with mss.mss() as sct:
    # Part of the screen to capture
    monitor = {"top": 40, "left": 0, "width": 800, "height": 640}
```

I hope someone can help me to improve my FPS.

Or should I use Yolov5n, if yes, how do I use / download it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to improve your FPS rate:

1. The easier, the better. Try with smaller models such as [YOLOv5s](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/releases) or YOLOv5n
2. What about using your GPU for inference? Add this line: --GPU. Example: $ python detect.py --source 0 --gpu #--source 0 = webcam, make sure you change it.
3. Reduce your field vision to only a small bounding box (try with 480x480) close to your weapon. Maybe you will need to resize your training set to meet this requirement.
4. Check this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yqwz4QGDNh0&ab_channel=SometimesRobots

Good luck!

PD. For further details about YOLOv5 usage, please visit the official website: https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/wiki/Train-Custom-Data

Comment: Hey, i am using CUDA, but how do I use smaller models like yolov5n? Do you know a tutorial or how I can do that? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Hey @Dani, you can change the model before training as follows: !python train.py --img 480 --batch 4 --epochs 100 --data defects.yaml --cfg models/yolov5s.yaml --weights yolov5s.pt --name your_trained_model --cache

Comment: Is a bigger or smaller batch size better?

Comment: It depends on your GPU memory. The larger the batch, the faster the training. Start with 14 and diminish it. PD. Do not forget to rename and change your YAML file.

Comment: Alright, thank you. What would be better for more FPS yolov5 or yolov4? And how can I use yolov5n (the nano model) ?

Comment: YOLOv5 is faster. PD. For further details about YOLOv5 usage, please visit the official website: https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/wiki/Train-Custom-Data

Comment: @Dani could you please tick the answer?